# How to show a specific data like schoolname from my data to console using nodejs?

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I am new to `nodejs` I have a database name `schooldetail` and I want to show only `schoolid` and `schoolname` in my console currently i am getting all the data which are in my `schooldetail database`.How can i do that using **res.send**? I am getting all the data in raw json format ?

```
router.get('/childarea', function (req, res, next) {

    //var area = req.query.area;

    /* this function will get us the areas from the database*/

    dbops.getArea(req, function (err, result) {
        console.log("error" + err + "result:" + result);
        if (result == "1")
            res.send({
                "Success":done
            });
        else
            res.send("does not exist");
    });
});

module.exports.getArea = function (child, callback) {
    sql.connect(db_config, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            sql.close();
            callback(err, null);
        } else {
            // create Request object
            var request = new sql.Request();

            /* query to get all details of the area */
            var areaQuery = "select * from dbo.tbl_Area";
            request.query(areaQuery, function (err, recordset) {
                sql.close();
                if (err)
                    console.log(err);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(recordset));
            });

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: if you want to get only schoolid and schoolname and you don't need others, you should change the `areaQuery` to `select schoolid, schoolname from dbo.tbl_Area`. 

but if you want to get all row data but logging schoolid and schoolname, you can access the `recordset` attributes by `.` and logging them instead of `recordset` itself

Comment: ok let me change and check

Comment: @Amirmasudzarebidaki can you please send me the code snippet that recordset part